# Error when trying to use function that returns a function that returns a HOC (a la Redux Connect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a Higher Order Component (HOC) that is like `connect` from `react-redux` but I'm running into errors.

My code can be found here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/483or78no0

I took this HOC code from this blog post:
https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e (look for `Appendix A: HOC and parameters`)

The error I get is: `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.` and nothing is rendered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a jsx tag in your `render` function:

```
render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Oh how dumb of me. Thank you!

Comment: I did this, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is because in the root, where you render `App`, you pass `App` as a function: `render(App, document.getElementById('root'));`.
Instead you need to pass it as a component (just like the error says): `render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));`

https://codesandbox.io/s/y077k1qy7j